# Smoothness of distributions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory, operator-algebras, pseudo-differential-operators

I've reached an impasse in reading some texts on distribution theory, as several of them mention smooth distributions, but none of them actually define what it means.
Therefore I'd like to know if anyone could give me the definition of a smooth distribution.
EDIT:
After reading a bit more, I've realized that I am thinking about distributions which are locally given by smooth functions. Where is it possible to read about these

Comment: Do you use any online references with that term? On its own I can't  make much sense of "smooth distributions". Distributions are infinitely differentiable, and you can associate a distribution to any compactly supported smooth function, but I wouldn't think that's what's meant...

Comment: Well, I don't have any open right now and I haven't been able to find them just now, but I do have Shubins book on pseudodifferential operators and spectral theory where we have the theorem: $Au=\int\int e^{i(x-y)}a(x,y,\xi)u(y)dy d\xi$ (an oscillatory integral), Then the kernel of $A$ (in the sense of Laurent Schwartz) satisfies $K_A\in C^{\infty}(X\times X \setminus \Delta)$ where $\Delta$ is the diagonal in $X\times X$.